# Flutter provider installation error while running pub get

Tags: flutter

I am trying to install provider(flutter package) but getting an error message when trying to run $ pub get :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1Itj.png)
Provider Package installation error:

Comment: Is your Flutter up to date?

Comment: @BenediktJSchlegel yes my flutter was not upto date.. it worked after updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your flutter sdk which is greater then 1.15.17, your current version of flutter SDK. then try to install the flutter package again..

The latest Stable release of flutter is v1.17.1 . So just update your flutter and  then add the your desired flutter package..

Comment: you are wellcome

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your flutter sdk with the command 'flutter upgrade', and only then try to install the provider package again.

try to always keep updated

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).